# How to perform multiclass multioutput classification using lstm

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, classification, lstm

I have `multiclass multioutput classification` (see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html for details). In other words, my dataset looks as follows.

```
node_name, timeseries_1, timeseries_2, label_1, label_2
node1, [1.2, ...], [1.8, ...], 0, 2
node2, [1.0, ...], [1.1, ...], 1, 1
node3, [1.9, ...], [1.2, ...], 0, 3 
...
...
...
```

So, my `label_1` could be either `0` or `1`, whereas my `label_2` could be either `0`, `1`, or `2`.

My current code is as follows.

```
def create_network():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(200, input_shape=(16,2)))
    model.add(Dense(100))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

neural_network = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_network, epochs=100, batch_size=100, verbose=0)

k_fold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=0)

scores = cross_validate(neural_network, my_features, label_data_encoded, cv=k_fold, scoring = ('accuracy', 'precision_weighted', 'recall_weighted', 'f1_weighted', 'roc_auc'))
```

My questions are as follows.

- Since I have two labels (i.e. `label_1` and `label_2`), how to fit these labels to lstm model? Do I have to do something like `keras.utils.to_categorical(label_1, 2)` and `keras.utils.to_categorical(label_2, 3)`?
- How to change the model in order to make it suitable for `multiclass multioutput classification`?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, label_1 is binary, whereas label_2 is a multiclass problem, so we need the model to have two outputs with separate loss functions; binary and categorical crossentropy respectively.

However, Sequential API does not allow multiple input/output.

> The Sequential API allows you to create models layer-by-layer for most problems. It is limited in that it does not allow you to create models that share layers or have multiple inputs or outputs.

You can use the functional API to create two output layers, and compile the model with required loss functions.

```
X=Input(input_shape)
X=Layer(X)
'
'
'
'
out1=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(X)
out2=Dense(3, activation='softmax')(X)
model = Model(inputs = input, outputs = [out1,out2])
model.compile(loss = ['binary_crossentropy','categorical_crossentropy'], loss_weights = [l1,l2], ...)

model.fit(input,[label_1, label_2_toCategotical]
```

The loss that the network will minimize will be the weighted sum of the 2 losses, weighted by l1 and l2.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. However, I have one further question. Since `kerasclassifier` does not support functional API, how can we perform 10-fold stratified cross validation using your approach. If you have the code/or know how to code it, please let me know. Looking forward to hearing from you. thank you :)

Comment: Oh well, not sure if I have an elegant solution, but you could use the sklearn StratifiedKFold to generate splits and then manually loop through the splits.

Comment: Thank you. Please post the code if you have sklearn StratifiedKFold manual loops. If not, I will check it in other SO questions :)

Comment: I have one further question. What is your suggested values for `l1` and `l2` in your code?

Comment: Moreover, it would also be great if you can tell me the input shape of label data? So as I understand, I only need to use `keras.utils.to_categorical(label_2, 3)`. Is it correct?

Comment: Correct regarding the shape for label_2. Label_1 is binary and remains so, so does not need any transformation.Regarding the `l1` and `l2` weights, I believe it would be fair to treat them as another hyper-parameter.  So you can start with setting both to 1, and then try tweaking if one of the outputs performs too badly.
Sorry I can't find the code for StratifiedKFold readily at hand, you can check with the official sklearn docs, or another answer indeed! :)

Comment: thank you very much. I have one last question. When I use `model.predict()`, suppose I got the following results; `out1 =0.52, out2 =[0.2,0.2,0.6]`. Does this mean that the predicted class labels are `out1=1, out2=2`? please let me know your thoughts :)

Comment: For label_1, the predicted class is 1 assuming a threshold of 0.5, which you can adjust. The label_2 predicts class=2, note that it is a softmax activation so it will have max probability assigned to one of the classes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat complicated problem, since the Scikit-Learn API and Keras API for multiclass multi-output are not directly compatible. Further, there are even differences in how TensorFlow v1 and v2 handle things. The existing Keras wrappers don't really work for more complex cases.

I created an extension of `KerasClassifier` that is able to deal with these situations, the package and documentation are [here (GitHub)](https://github.com/adriangb/scikeras). Full disclosure: I am the the creator of the package, but I have no financial interests, it's open source.

With these extended versions, you can easily handle multiclass multi-output problems. I think for your situation it should work out of the box, but if not you can just inherit from `KerasClassifier` and overwrite `target_encoder` to transform from the Scikit-Learn data format to whatever your Keras Model uses. More details [here (docs)](https://github.com/adriangb/scikeras).

Hope this helps!